# How to peel off grating layer from CD-R?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I wanted to create a grating based surface plasmon resonance setup, but I don't want to spend to money to get a grating manufactured. I realized that we can extract a grating by peeling off the metal layer from a CD-R. However, I am not sure how I can peel of the gratings from the CD. I tried regular tape, but it did not peel anything off. I then tried super glue which did peel of the layer but it appears to be damaged. Is there a protocol and manual that describes how I can carefully peel the gratings from the CD?

Comment: Try textile or aluminum tape and various peeling methods (slow, quick, various directions of pull). I've seen it is capable to tear a big patch of aluminum layer off CD or DVD. Before attempting to peel the layer off, push a wet towel against the tape and massage the tape to make sure it sticks very well at all points.

Comment: Something like [this pdf](https://nnin.org/sites/default/files/files/Karen_Rama_USING_CDs_AND_DVDs_AS_DIFFRACTION_GRATINGS_0.pdf) seems to give clear instructions. (They aren't after the metalic parts, but you can clearly see the peeled metallic grating in the photos.)